# Delete comma in front of currency woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

On a website i am currently working on i cannot figure out/remove a comma in front of my € sign. Prices look like this: 8,67 ,€ everywhere.

It really start to working on my nerves right now because i cannot remove it. We want to go live with the website tommorrow. any help would be appriciated.

Kind regards,

Dennie

Comment: Is the comma on the admin site on the product data page e.g. "Regular Price (,€)"? If it is then it's coming from get_woocommerce_currency_symbol, probably from a woocommerce_currency_symbols or woocommerce_currency_symbol filter then you must have defined somewhere.

Comment: Or equally can you check the markup for the price? Is the comma inside the `<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">` ?

Comment: <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"> "€" ","   it looks like this. but i do not know where to delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this setting, WooCommerce > Settings > General.

[image]

If that isn't it check that you don't have a plugin installed that is effecting it.  Disable them one at a time and check.

Comment: done that, does not make any difference